# ES6 Modules: transitively exporting symbols (i.e., from imported files)

Tags: import, ecmascript-6

Suppose I'm creating an ES6 library with multiple files, but have a root file that contains all of the top-level definitions. How could I achieve something like this example:

```
lib/foo/sub.js
export class Sub{}

lib/main.js
import { Sub } from './foo/sub'

client.js
# This doesn't work.
import { Sub } from 'lib/main'
```

I.e., where client only imports from the top-level file (since the sub levels are implementation details -- and later on will likely be encapsulated into a single minified file (but at development time are in multiple files).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to re-export:

```
lib/main.js
import { Sub } from './foo/sub';
export { Sub };
```

You can re-export directly like this:

```
export { Sub } from './foo/sub';
```

You can rename when exporting:

```
export { Sub as MySub } from './foo/sub';
```

Or re-export everything:

```
export * from './foo/sub';
```

Comment: Thanks @torazaburo for the super-quick response.

Comment: Which environments don't support `export … from`?

Comment: I was being conservative, remembering that es6-module-transpiler did not support that, but I see that it is now deprecated in favor of babel+esperanto.

Comment: You forgot to mention `export * as utils from './utils'`, it also may be very useful.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny Where is that syntax documented? I also cannot figure out what it would mean. In babel, that syntax generates a syntax error at the point of `as`.

Comment: @torazaburo it's from [`es7.exportExtensions` proposal](https://github.com/leebyron/ecmascript-more-export-from#proposed-additions). I'm using ES7 right now and totally forgot that this particular syntax is not a part of ES6.